# How to calculate profit formula with multiple user input text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a simple calculation formula but I don't know how to add all the variables simultaneously.

I already tried this but it is giving an error and is being super inaccurate.

```
var fee :Int = Int(0.866)
var otherFee:Int = Int(0.30)    

@IBAction func calculateProfit(_ sender: Any) {
    let sold = Int(soldTextField.text!)!
    let paid = Int(paidTextField.text!)!
    let shipping = Int(shippingTextField.text!)!

    profitTotal.text = String(sold * fee - otherFee - paid - shipping )
}
```

I suspect that when I hit the button it will multiply, subtract, subtract simultaneously.

Comment: Use parentheses to group operations? Give an example of all the inputs and what the right answer would be.

Comment: Hint - what is the value of `0.866` as an Integer ? Throw away everything to the right of the decimal point. What is anything multiplied by 0?

Comment: I would recommend you to read the first couple of chapters of the excellent book [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) to learn about data types, operators etc

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to calculate and what fee and otherFee are? Maybe an example with values and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fee :Int = Int(0.866)
var otherFee:Int = Int(0.30)
```

Now both values are `0`. And multiplying other values with this will return `0`. Don't use `Int` for such calculations. Use `Double` like

```
var fee = 0.866
var otherFee = 0.30

@IBAction func calculateProfit(_ sender: Any) {
    let sold = Double(soldTextField.text!) ?? 0
    let paid = Double(paidTextField.text!) ?? 0
    let shipping = Double(shippingTextField.text!) ?? 0

    profitTotal.text = String(sold * fee - otherFee - paid - shipping)
}
```

Comment: Better to conditionally unwrap the conversion to double. `Decimal` might be better for currency too

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide **Default** value also for Textfield text because **Force Unwrapping** **soldTextfield.text** lead to crashes if there is no text inside textfield.

```
Double(soldTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
```

Same also for other textfields

Comment: This is not a complete answer and what you wrote is already part of an existing answer so this answer adds no value.

Comment: The previous answer was good. I just added a tweak. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Please add a complete answer, this one is more suitable as a comment